# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) issue

Tags: android

I am using the Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) sample code for both client & server.
I have successfully setup the server using Apache Tomcat & also created the Android application (apk) following the steps provided on the tutorial.

After deploying the war file on the Apache Tomcat, I am able to register from emulator. I have provided a Public IP for the Tomcat server & able to view the "registered screen" from the mobile Browser using GPRS.

I have followed all the steps provided on the GCM tutorial.

Is there any issue with the sample code of the GCM?

I am getting the following exception when I am clicking on a button to send Message to the registered device:

> com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status
>   Code: 401
>     com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:177)
>     com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
>     com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:82)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

I have gone through some similar posts but am not finding any exact solution on the issue.
Any suggestions / hints will be helpful.

Comment: set server url and sender code to your android project code.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using tomcat as server, to fixe it I modified this file

`WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/api.key` replacing the content with the API Key extracted from the google api console.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Google has updated their api console recently to Google Cloud Console. In short terms , you need to create an Android application and pick Accessing APIs via a web server. [this service has a detailed guide for that](https://github.com/PushAppsService/PushAppsSDK/tree/master/Android/Guides)

Answer (score 0):

That's the Not Authorized return code.  Your server app is not authenticated to the GCM server.  Did you generate yourself an API key in the developer console?

Comment: I have tried with both the Server & Browser API Key for the specific project & also able to register a device using the emulator. Only when I try to send a Message to the emulator , the above exception displays

Comment: 401 error means authentication issues, I think you should try to reissue your API key : http://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/Android+Getting+Started